# Not being told what happens after placement

Tags: management, united-kingdom, training, employment

I've been working as an apprentice for the last 1 and a half years in a programming/web development role. I'm really enjoying the company that I work in and would like to continue after my apprenticeship.

I am learning a lot and quickly but my time is coming close to an end and I know it would be too hard for me to go into any other job including junior developer as my experience and knowledge is just far too limited as a lot of my role currently doesn't involve programming and only recently have I started progressing with that aspect.

There has been talk of doing the next level of apprenticeship but with only a couple months left and no follow up on this topic I have mentioned to my mentors and coaches and they said I would find out soon whether it is possible for me to do it (based off funding) as they believe I have the capability to do the next level. I have won awards as an apprentice within the organisation but I know it will mean nothing outside of the company due to lacking experience.

However I will need to begin looking for new jobs just to back it up but I don't want to accept anything until I have a definite answer from the current employer.

**Question:** How do I get a definite answer from my current employer so I can decide what I want to do after the apprenticeship

**EDIT:** I do not want to do another apprenticeship and start from scratch with another employer as I want to move on and progress.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your manager and asking bluntly? *"I am interested with continuing employment after my apprenticeship."*

Comment: I have yes and they just keep saying we have to get back to you, "you'll find out soon" but soon has been a few months now

Comment: An apprenticeship for programming/web development that doesn't involve a lot of programming. I think you've been sold a bad job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I will need to begin looking for new jobs just to back it up but I don't want to accept anything until I have a definite answer from the current employer.
>
> Question: How do I get a definite answer from my current employer so I can decide what I want to do after the apprenticeship

Decide on a reasonable date, then just be honest and tell it like it is to your current employer. It sounds like you have a pretty goot rapport with them, so this shouldn't cause any problems.

Something like:

> Hi `x`,
>
> As you know, I've had a great time working here over the last 18 months and I'm certainly hoping to be able to continue to work here in a further apprenticeship. I understand this isn't something that can be confirmed right now, but I'm going to need to know for definite by (date) so I can start searching for other roles if necessary - will this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at advanced or higher apprenticeships or similar training programmes (assuming your current programme isn't already an advanced apprenticeship)? Maybe if you start early you could keep your options open.

I'm sure if you've won awards, this will look very positive on your application.

> How do I get a definite answer from my current employer so I can decide what I want to do after the apprenticeship

This will be difficult as sometimes in business it takes til the last second before things are finalised (not always ideal). As I've mentioned, you could look for further training to keep your options open but just ensure to bring it up with your manager or coaches and show that you are keen to continue working for the company if the further training offer becomes available.

> I do not want to do another apprenticeship and start from scratch with another employer as I want to move on and progress.

As much as you'd like to progress, if the option isn't there an advanced or higher apprenticeship is a progression in it's own right and often these things present opportunities such as gaining a degree whilst working or job rotations, which could look very desirable to future employers considering your applications.

Good Luck!